# Best practive for logging errors (handled and unhandled) in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I know that you can use the **[HandleError]** attribute on controllers to redirect users to a shared (or even custom) Error.cshtml page for unhandled exceptions.

However I would also like to log these exceptions to a database and/or flat file.

What is the preferred approach?

Comment: "Best Practice" questions are not a good fit for SO. There is no right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to logging error.

[Elmah At Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ELMAH)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ELMAH to log errors to log file or to database in an HandleError Attribute](http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-4--handleerrorattribute)

Alternative you can go with [Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application Block](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10255/Exception-Handling-Logging-Application-Block-Enter)

One more option is to use [Log4Net](http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/logging-in-mvc-part-4-log4net/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree on ELMAH being the best choice, but rather than implementing your own HandleError attribute (as proposed), you should check out the [Elmah.MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah.mvc) package, which adds painless integration of ELMAH into your MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new service which can automatically catch all unhandled errors (and also display an  error page): http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/01/onetrueerror-and-asp-net/

Another option is to override [Error method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in global.asax. It's the only place which will catch all errors (as the MVC error filter only captures MVC errors).